How to synchronise paracol headings?
I read the paracol documentation and quite don't understand it.
I tried these options:

Use \switchcolumn*[\section{NAME}\label{sec:ABBRV}]
Use \begin{leftcolumn*}[\section{NAME}\label{sec:ABBRV}] \end{leftcolumn*}; begin{rightcolumn*}[\section{NAME}\label{sec:ABBRV}] \end{rightcolumn*}
Use \begin{column*}[\section{NAME}\label{sec:ABBRV}] \end{column*}

And how much I try I cannot get the sections, even though they have the same label to be exactly in the same place.
Imagine:
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn*}[\section{Section I - Introduction}\label{sec:intro}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{leftcolumn*}
\begin{rightcolumn*}[\section{Section I - Introduction}\label{sec:intro}] % Other language.
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{rightcolumn*}

\begin{leftcolumn*}[\section{Section II - Something}\label{sec:smnt}]
\lipsum[5-6]
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn*}[\section{Section II - Something}\label{sec:smnt}] % Other language.
\lipsum[7-8]
\end{rightcolumn*}
\end{paracol}

That was just an example of how it would go. First the section in English which is on left side is written with section, subsections etc.
Then the right side is written in a different language.
Then the next section on the left side should be written, and as you know the section location will be different for this side as well as for the other side.
In short:
I need the headings to be synchronised at the same level.
Imagine 2 headings on both sides should be at the same level, so it is easier for the reader to understand.
Something like this:
+-------+
|1. | 1.|
|-- |-- |
|-- |   |
|2. | 2.|
|-- |-- |
+-------+

EDIT: It works thanks to MS-SPO, and now the problem is that the second column's section is not at the same level as the first column's section, it is always one text below.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Column switching commands
\newcommand{\EN}{\switchcolumn[0]}
\newcommand{\LV}{\switchcolumn[1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\EN*[\section{Column Synchronization}]
\lipsum[1-5]

\LV\section{Column Synchronization}
\lipsum[5-7]

\EN*[\section{Next Line}]
\lipsum[5-8]

\LV\section{Next Line}
\lipsum[9-12]

\end{paracol}

2ND EDIT: IT IS NOW IN LEVEL BECAUSE I ACTUALLY REMOVED THE OPTIONAL ARGUMENT PART, AND MADE THE SECTION JUST BE LIKE THAT
\begin{paracol}{2}
\EN*
\section{Column Synchronization}
\lipsum[1-5]

\LV
\section{Column Synchronization}
\lipsum[5-7]

\EN*
\section{Next Line}
\lipsum[5-8]

\LV
\section{Next Line}
\lipsum[9-12]

\end{paracol}

THANK YOU MS-SPO and Werner!!

Welcome. // Can you please add the few missing lines so your code will compile when we copy and run it? Thank you // Where did you synchronize both columns? See Ch. 3 ? \switchcolumn[0]*[ \section{Column Synchronization}  in the User Manual https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol (\switchcolum is the one you want)

If you want the sectional headings to line up, then don't use the optional argument for \switchcolumn, as they provide spanning text; this means the text will span all the columns. Instead, just switch between the columns and set the \sections as normal.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Column switching commands
\newcommand{\EN}{\switchcolumn[0]}
\newcommand{\LV}{\switchcolumn[1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\EN*\section{Column Synchronization}
\lipsum[1]

\LV\section{Column Synchronization}
\lipsum[2]

\EN*\section{Next Line}
\lipsum[3]

\LV\section{Next Line}
\lipsum[4]

\end{paracol}

\end{document}

